# Send the array current value to load model when iterating the array itself

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to store each value in an array to load a view when the array itself is being iterated. I've been using `for` to make it happen as the following code :

```
$seat = (0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3=> 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k');
$number = 10;
for ($i=0; $i <= $number; $i++) { 
    $this->data['chunked'] = $seat[$i];
    $this->load->view('chunked', $this->data);
}
```

How do I apply the same thing using `foreach`, send the array's current value when iterating the array `$seat` itself?

```
 foreach ($seat as $key => $value) {

    $this->data['chunked'] = //how to set the current array value being iterated
    $this->load->view('chunked', $this->data);

 }
```

The point is, I want to generate some columns using `<div>` based on how many array key in `$seat` I have. So in this case, I have 11 Keys started from 0 to 10. I want the columns to be generated at the same time the array being iterated. In the end I'll have 11 `<div>` columns

Comment: question is unclear. one guess is `$this->data['chunked'] = $value;`

Comment: can you post  your $number array ??

Comment: Why are loading view in for loop ??

Comment: I want to generate some columns using `<div>` based on how many array key in `$seat` I have. So in this case, I have 11 Keys started from 0 to 10. I want the columns to be generated at the same time the array being iterated. In the end I'll have 11 `<div>` columns @Drudge

Comment: $seat[$key]; should achieve the same result.

Comment: worked perfectly, the answer is so simple. I'm so ashamed :) Thanks @baboizk

Comment: @AnggieAriWidhia not a problem man. i will post it as an answer so others can also learn or see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($seat as $key => $value) {

 $this->data['chunked'] = $seat[$key]; //how to set the current array value being iterated
 $this->load->view('chunked', $this->data);

}
```

to achieve exactly the same you can do this adding

```
$seat[$key];
```